# While Outlook is running, my program(win32.client) does not working

Tags: python

I made a mail sending program through python and gui.
However, my program created with win32.client and outlook do not run at the same time.

Running the code in VScode works fine even if outlook is running.

However, if you run it after making it with pyinstaller -w, an error occurs when outlook is running. If outlook is not running, it will run without problems, but outlook cannot be run.

All of the below are causing problems.

```
import win32.client as win32
...
outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application') -- failed
...

#outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application') -- failed as well
#outlook = win32.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") -- failed
#outlook = win32.GetObject(None, "Outlook.Application") -- didn't expect

            #outlook = win32.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application")
            #olmailitem = 0x0
            #mail = outlook.CreateItem(olmailitem)

            mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

            subject = " "
            body =" "
            mail.To = to
            for path in attachments:
                mail.Attachments.Add(path)
            mail.Send()
```

If I call outlook.application, it seems to be a problem because it is a duplicate call with outlook execution.

So I thought about using outlook.mailItem, but it doesn't work properly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is anybody there?

Answer (score 1):

I have:

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
```

Notice the case on outlook and appplication

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 86, in _GetGoodDispatch
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, '작업을 사용할 수 없습니다.', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-2.2.0.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "win32com\client\__init__.py", line 117, in Dispatch
  File "win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 106, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
  File "win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 88, in _GetGoodDispatch
pywintypes.com_error: (-2146959355, '서버 실행이 실패했습니다.', None, None)